# Building command line window app using python

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I want to build a command line window app using python. It  takes input from user , processes it and then gives the output back. Any suggestions where to start like libraries, functions etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple command-line interface python program, you shouldn't need any external libraries. You could use the built in `print()` function to get output to the user, as well as the built in `input()` function in order to receive input. More information can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp).

Comment: thanks for the answer. one more thing, is there any way to run your python program as an executable file as we usually do in C/C++

Comment: You can use the py2exe program in order to generate an executable out of a python program, but due to how python is interpreted and different than c/c++,  it is not recommended.